# Integrate ZOHO Recruit API?

Tags: api

I'm working with a client using ZOHO Recruit to manage his staffing agency. The form for candidates to submit their information is given by ZOHO as a simple embed code. However, for employers to submit their jobs, it must use ZOHO's API - which is beyond what i know how to do so far.

I'm all up for learning and have been looking for tutorials, but I can't find a good starting place to learn. Here is what ZOHO sent - anyone around to give me a starting place to know what to do with this?

http://www.zoho.com/recruit/api.html
http://www.zoho.com/recruit/add-records.html

Comment: Are you trying to integrate ZOHO API data into WordPress, or merely embed an application?

Comment: I want to make available on one of my WordPress sites the option for an employer to add a job opening. I don't need to display the job openings themselves - but the form that allows an employer to submit a new job opening that then gets passed to ZOHO Recruit - that's what I need to display on the site. ZOHO responded with the two links above saying it is done using their API's, but I just don't know what to do with it (even though they give what I think are some pretty clear instructions!).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what you'll need to do is XML-ize your data and POST it to the API URLs they provide. I'll start out with the basic request, and we can build on the solution if you want.

```
<?php
    $api_key = 'API_KEY'; // insert your API key here;
    $ticket = 'TICKET_ID'; // your ticket here (should be with your account);
    $data = 
        "<JobOpenings>
        <row no='1'>
        <FL val='Posting title'>$job_title</FL>
        <FL val='Client'>$client</FL>
        <FL val='Assigned recruiter'>$recruiter_id</FL>
        <FL val='Job opening status'>$job_status</FL>
        <FL val='Number of positions'>$num_positions</FL>
        <FL val='Country'>$job_country</FL>
        <FL val='Roles and responsibilities'>$job_description</FL>
        </row>
        </JobOpenings>";

    ?>
```

You'd need to populate those variables with the values you've collected from the user. Then, you need to make a POST request. You can use the [WP_Http class](http://planetozh.com/blog/2009/08/how-to-make-http-requests-with-wordpress/) for that:

```
<?php
    if( !class_exists( 'WP_Http' ) )
        include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC. '/class-http.php' );

    $url = "https://recruit.zoho.com/ats/private/xml/Module/addRecords?apikey=$api_key&ticket=$ticket";
    $request = new WP_Http;
    $result = $request->request( $url, array( 'method' => 'POST', 'body' => $data) );
```

Now, obviously you'll need to do some tweaking to add the data you'll need for your posting, and you'll need to handle the case that the request fails. But I hope this gives you a start (I can't guarantee the code will work 100%) - let me know and we can build on it!

Comment: To follow up, thank you for the responses. I had to have a developer work with me on this because I didn't feel like I could quickly enough work through your suggestions. From what he said though, they were correct!

Comment: No problem - glad I was sorta right, at least!